# Sessão Laravel - Public para Controller

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

Estou fazendo um formulário que contém um **Captcha**.
O **Captcha** é gerado por um script PHP que monta uma imagem.

E eu coloquei o script na pasta *public* do **Laravel 4**.

Quando o código do **Captcha** é gerado é colocado em sessão:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['numCaptcha'] = $code;
```

Depois ao enviar os dados do formulário, envio para um **Controller**, que tem a função:

```
public function enviaContato() {
   echo $_SESSION['numCaptcha'];
   die();

   # Verificação de Captcha
   if (empty(Session::get('numCaptcha')) || strcasecmp(Session::get('numCaptcha'), Input::get('numCaptcha')) != 0) {
      Session::flash('error', "Captcha Inválido");
   }
}
```

Desse jeito que fiz acima não está pegando o valor da sessão. Já fiz também:

`Session::get('numCaptcha')`

Mas também não funcionou.

Ecziste alguma restrição ? 
 Tem como fazer de outra forma ?

Então, como fazer uso da sessão do *public*  para o **Controller**.

Comment: Você não acha melhor usar uma biblioteca de captcha `Laravel` ?

Comment: Pode ser. Tem alguma na manga ?

Comment: Usei essa para o `Laravel 4`. Ele usa o session do próprio laravel e o `validation`. É bom sempre tentar utilizar o máximo (ou tudo) que é recurso do `Laravel`. https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha/tree/master-l4

Comment: Pra gerar a imagem basta fazer no HTML `{{ Captcha::img() }}`. Eu gosto muito! Eu uso nesse sistema : http://pbh.portaltmt.com.br

Comment: Pois é. Tenho consciência disso. Mas a versão do Laravel desse site que estou atualizando é o 4.0. Dá até receio de atualizar o `composer.json` e dar problema no site.

Comment: É. Se fosse pelo menos o `Laravel 4.2`. Pode acreditar: Do `4.0` para o `4.2` existem alguns recursos que já me fazem falta (se estivesse usando o `4.0`)

Comment: Não custa nada tentar, já mandei rodar aqui o composer com a biblioteca.

Comment: No way. Não funcionou nessa versão. **The requested package mews/captcha could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você deve verificar a configuração do `Laravel`. O Laravel (como a maioria dos frameworks), não usa a sessão nativa do PHP. Não me lembro se há alguma forma de configurar isso.

Sendo assim, as sessões de `$_SESSION` e `Session::get` são salvos em mecanismos diferentes (O PHP salva da sua forma padrão, e o Laravel salva num arquivo dentro da pasta `app/storage`).

Então, ou seu código tem que ser transformado para "php puro" ou para "laravel puro".

Você citou nos comentários que não conseguiu instalar a biblioteca desejada. Então, aqui vai um captcha "na mão" (uma solução em "laravel quase puro") que eu utilizei um de nossos sistema em `Laravel` - Talvez seja útil no seu caso.

```
Route::get('captcha', function()
{

    $word = [0 => null, 1 => null];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $word[0] .= chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
        $word[1] .= chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
    }

    $word = implode(' ', $word);


    Session::put('captcha_word', $word);

    $font = public_path('recaptcha/fonts/recaptchaFont.ttf');

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(172, 50);

    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 172, 99, $white);
    imagettftext($image, 22, 0, 5, 35, $color, $font, Session::get('capcha_word'));

    $tempCapcha = tempnam(null, 'captcha');

    imagepng($image, $tempCapcha);

    return Response::make(File::get($tempCapcha), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);
});
```

A verificação se daria da seguinte forma:

```
if (Session::get('captcha_word') == Input::get('algum_input_com_captcha'))
{

}
```

E no HTML, pra exibir o Captcha, você poderia fazer assim:

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('captcha') }}?{{ Str::random(8) }}" />
```

**Observação**: Observe que é necessário salvar a fonte usada pelo Captcha no `path` especificado na rota.

**Atualização**: O trecho da variável `$word` pode ser alterado para o código ficar mais limpo, usando apenas uma linha para declará-lo.

Assim:

```
$word = trim(chunk_split(Str::random(8), 4, ' '));
```

Comment: Deu certo. Uma observação apenas é os nomes das suas variáveis de sessão estão diferentes no código. Não sei se você alterou para postar aqui. **capcha** e **captcha**.

Comment: Não, é o nosso código que está errado. Vou alterar no meu sistema. Tenho mania de escrever `captcha` errado